# Video Booth / Video Guest Book for Events

Tags: video, digital-recording

I am looking for a solution for windows/linux to create a video guest book for a wedding. The application would run on a netbook or a laptop with a front facing webcam. Basically, people should be able to come up to the screen, hit a record button, talk or whatever, then hit stop and it should save. Maybe have the option to delete if they get flustered, etc.

I would prefer if it was something that could run in a kiosk mode so people don't mess with it, if it has cute features which would make it easier for the guests that fine. Free, FOSS, or commerical options will all be considered. I have not yet bought the netbook or laptop for this yet, and I can reload it with whatever OS or dependencies are needed. I found a few for "photo booth" like applications, but I want to do video.

Comment: I am thinking it might be easier to get an IP webcam that just records nonstop or even just a webcam, maybe one that is motion activated? I can still keep a screen up and maybe find a program that indicates whether it is or is not recording so they know. I can always get a fake button so people think they are activating, might be funny to see the practice what they want to say.

Comment: I suspect you'd have better luck with a "camera man" who ran the equipment, and showed the preview to the guests. This camera man would delete and re-shoot if the guest wasn't happy with what they recorded.  I wouldn't expect my grandmother, or my kid cousins to be able to use even a simple video kiosk at my wedding. And even if it was simple enough that they could, I suspect many would be too intimidated to try.

Comment: @Flimzy They have commercial kiosks you can rent for like $1000 USD - paying a camera man would be more costly at that and be less "cool". We decided specifically not to get a videographer for the wedding because we want to remember the memories the way we want :-)

Answer (score 1):

The "Photo Booth" application on OS X can record video, and is pretty simple to use

You could probably lock it down with the parental settings

An iPad 2 has the same thing, although it might be more easily misplacable